# What is the difference between elementsEqual and '==' in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sequence

I'm going through the Swift Standard Library, and I came across the method [elementsEqual](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2853688-elementsequal) for comparing sequences.

I'm not really seeing the value of this function because it will only return true if the order is exactly the same. I figured this would have some use if it could tell me if two sequences contained the same elements, they just happen to be in a different order, as that would save me the trouble of sorting both myself.

Which brings me to my question:

Is there any difference between using elementsEqual and '==' when comparing two sequences? Are there pros and cons for one vs the other?

I am in my playground, and have written the following test:

`let values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let otherValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
values == otherValues
values.elementsEqual(otherValues)`

both of these checks result in true, so I am not able to discern a difference here.

Comment: There is no `==` operator for sequences.

Comment: "=" sets a value.  For example myNumber: Int = 3.  "==" tests to see if a value is equal to another.  If myNumber == 3 { Do Something } else { ...

Comment: @MartinMuldoon This has nothing to do with `=` vs `==`.

Comment: @MartinR But `let aa = 1...3
let bb = 1...3
if aa == bb {
    print("hello")
}` works.

Comment: @rmaddy: There is a `==` operator for CountableClosedRange: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countableclosedrange/2428405.

Comment: There is also a `==` operator for *arrays* of equatable elements: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1539758, and that is what `values == otherValues` invokes.

Comment: Why does there need to be a difference? Its syntactic sugar ... that just happens to work in swift, and perhaps even some other languages too. You could ask the same question to loops, all programming languages contain different ways of looping thru statements, some subtle different to others, and yet some may seem identical. But hey why not test your own question, look at say performance; create a set of 1 million numbers , compare it using the two operators and see if they both come back with the same speed!

Comment: @rmaddy But what Martin is saying is that there isn't an `==` overload for all sequences of `Equatable` elements – try `AnySequence([1, 2, 3]) == AnySequence([1, 2, 3])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After playing with this for a while to find a practical example for the below original answer I found a much more simple difference: With `elementsEqual` you can compare collections of different types such as `Array`, `RandomAccessSlice` and `Set`, while with `==` you can't do that:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
let slice = 1...3
let set: Set<Int> = [1, 2, 3] // remember that Sets are not ordered

array.elementsEqual(slice) // true
array.elementsEqual(set) // false
array == slice // ERROR
array == set // ERROR
```

As to what exactly is different, @Hamish provided links to the implementation in the comments below, which I will share for better visibility:

- [elementsEqual](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L338)
- [==](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L2166)

**My original answer:**

Here's a sample playground for you, that illustrates that there is a  difference:

```
import Foundation

struct TestObject: Equatable {
    let id: Int
    static func ==(lhs: TestObject, rhs: TestObject) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

// TestObjects are never equal - even with the same ID
let test1 = TestObject(id: 1)
let test2 = TestObject(id: 1)
test1 == test2 // returns false

var testArray = [test1, test2]
var copiedTestArray = testArray

testArray == copiedTestArray // returns true
testArray.elementsEqual(copiedTestArray) // returns false
```

Maybe someone knows for sure, but my guess is that `==` computes something like `memoryLocationIsEqual || elementsEqual` (which stops evaluating after the memory location is indeed equal) and `elementsEqual` skips the memory location part, which makes `==` faster, but `elementsEqual` more reliable.

Comment: Your implementation of `==` violates the semantic requirements of `Equatable` (namely it isn't reflexive), so unexpected behaviour is expected.

Comment: You are correct that unexpected behavior is expected and I can't think of a good example from the top of my head where this would ever apply, BUT my answer is valid Swift code and it's the answer to OPs question: "Is there any difference between using elementsEqual and '==' when comparing two sequences?"

Comment: My point is that should *never* apply – because `TestObject` doesn't have a valid `Equatable` conformance. Conforming to a protocol is more than just implementing the requirements – you also need to adhere to its semantic requirements.

Comment: why is testArray.elementsEqual(testSet) false? isn't the whole point that it return true since they have the same elements?

Comment: @Hamish Yes, you are absolutely right. My code in the original answer should never go into production. Nevertheless it shows an underlying difference in the two functions `==` and `elementsEqual`, which I wanted to proof since the comments above (just syntactic sugar etc.) were definitely wrong. I updated my answer since your last comment with another solution to the problem.

Comment: @RDSpinz Because `Set` has no order and `elementsEqual` checks for same elements in the same order.

Comment: @BennoKress I would just make a direct comparison between the implementations of the two functions then ;) (https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift.gyb#L338 & https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb#L2166) – you were right in saying that `Array`'s implementation of `==` can short-circuit upon the arrays sharing the same buffer.

Comment: @Hamish nice, didn't think of looking there ... it's late :D

Comment: @RDSpinz Added another (better) example now with RandomAccessSlice which evaluates to true, because that has order ;)